# aschroder SMTP Pro Extension SES not sending transactional emails

Tags: cron, ce-1.9.2.2, smtp, amazonses

The self test email sends just fine using the SMTP Pro Extension configured with AWS SES, but no transactional emails will send. I've tested the welcome email, forgot password email, purchase confirmation email, and shipped email. In settings, under

```
system->configuration->SMTP Pro->Queue Configuration->Queue Usage
```

I've set it to never. I've also edited the file

```
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php
```

on line 1356, replacing

```
$mailer->setQueue($emailQueue)->send();
```

with

```
$mailer->send();
```

To by pass the cron queue. I know its a bad idea to edit the core files, but I'm looking to fix the issue first, then I'll move the solution to its own local file. I have enabled both Log Emails and Debug Logging. Only the self-test email appears in the log, and the error log file under var/log/aschroder_smtppro.log is never generated. The apache user has write permissions for var/.

I'm at my wits end. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Check for conflicts

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the SMTP Pro code is not even running. You need to debug through the core email sending code where it gets the Email Template object, it should be the SMTP Pro version of that model, but my guess is it's not. Could be caused by an undetected extension clash *or something*.

Answer (score 1):

After much digging, I realized that I was still in sandbox mode (in AWS; for those new to SES new accounts start off in sandbox mode and you have to have the account approved by amazon before you can go live). I'll go stand in a corner.

PS when you have multiple AWS accounts that you work with its somewhat understandable.

Answer (score 1):

Use this method [magento smtp](http://www.sohaib.com/2016/07/10/how-to-use-gmail-or-amazon-ses-with-magento/) instead it's easier and much more powerful no extension required